# Should JetBrains.Annotations be declared as a private asset in my csproj files?

Tags: c#, annotations, resharper

I've recently installed ReSharper and I'm refactoring a number of my C# solutions. As part of this process, I've added references to `JetBrains.Annotations` in my projects. However, I'm not sure whether I should be marking this dependency as private (to prevent it being passed on as a dependency to higher-level projects) or whether doing this will potentially break things.

In other words, I'm not sure whether I should be doing this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="11.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Or simply this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="11.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

From the [NuGet package documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations):

> All usages of ReSharper Annotations attributes are erased from metadata by default, which means no actual binary reference to 'JetBrains.Annotations.dll' assembly is produced.

If I'm understanding this correctly, it suggests that marking the package as private should be safe. However, I just want to confirm.

Comment: I've found a [very useful reference](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/) for this - trying out the suggested approach now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I'm understanding this correctly, it suggests that marking the package as private should be safe. However, I just want to confirm.

That's correct. There's two things in play here; metadata references (in the assembly) and NuGet package references.

Because the JetBrains annotations are conditionally compiled (using `[Conditional("JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS")]`), as long as you don't define `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS`, all traces of the annotations will be removed from the assembly itself. This also means that it's safe to remove the NuGet package reference.

However, if you *do* define `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS`, you should also include the NuGet package reference.

See [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Annotations_in_Source_Code.html) for more information...

Comment: Thanks. I'm intending to use these annotations in library projects that will be consumed only within my company, and probably just by myself. I want the higher-level projects I write to benefit from these annotations. Based on what you wrote and [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/08/12/how-to-use-jetbrains-annotations-to-improve-resharper-inspections/), it seems like I *should* compile with `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS` and therefore *should* expose `JetBrains.Annotations` as a dependency. Currently looking into the best way of appending compilation symbols in csproj.

Comment: If you're consuming the assemblies through NuGet, then yes. If all projects are in the same solution, I don't think it's needed.

Comment: I'm publishing my projects and consuming them through NuGet. They'll be in separate solutions.

Comment: Also, if you'd like users of your package to benefit from the annotations you add, you can also add the annotations as source, by copying them from the options page and adding a new file in your project. These will be created as `internal`, meaning no-one else will use them, but ReSharper will see them and make use of them when someone references your assembly.